# Installing Scala 2.10.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: scala, ubuntu, dpkg

I am having problems trying to install the .deb file for Scala version 2.10.2.

I am getting the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 372442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace scala 2.9.1.dfsg-3 (using .../Downloads/scala-2.10.2.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement scala ...
dpkg: error processing /home/chris/Downloads/scala-2.10.2.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar', which is also in package scala-library 2.9.1.dfsg-3
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed in write on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/chris/Downloads/scala-2.10.2.deb
```

Do you guys have any idea of why I would be getting this?

Comment: Try to uninstall your previous Scala package before installing the new one.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately

Comment: Did you get a different error message the second time? Because I'd be surprised if you're seeing "trying to overwrite '/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar', which is also in package scala-library 2.9.1.dfsg-3" after you've uninstalled scala 2.9.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar` is in package `scala-library`. You must remove both then install the 2.10.2 package:

```
apt-get remove scala-library scala
dpkg -i  /home/chris/Downloads/scala-2.10.2.deb
```

In more details, plagiarizing your output log:

1) `dpkg` is installing a new version of the `scala` package:

```
Unpacking replacement scala ...
```

2) While checking if everything will go well, it realised that if unpacking the `scala` package, it will replace a file from another package named `scala-library`:

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/java/scala-library.jar', which is also in package scala-library 2.9.1.dfsg-3
```

3) It desided to stop before doing bad things.